# Windows 2012 file share always asks for password

Tags: windows, windows-7, network-share

We have a file share here on a windows 2012 server. On login it ask for password.On the client (Windows 7) I have the option "save password". But even if I click this, after next reboot of the client, I have to enter the password again.

Why is the stored password not used and why do I have to reenter it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the passwords stored on the client computer, you have to open the credential manager.

To do so : win + r, then you type "control userpasswords2"

You choose the tab "advanced", and then click on "manage passwords".

I already had this issue, because the login was the same on the client and on the server, with different passwords.